# how to load model data from database to listbox in java zk project with mvc design pattern?

Tags: model-view-controller, listbox, zk

I am unable to load data from database to listbox in my zk project

I have this index.zul file with a listbox which cycles through a list of bank accounts

```
<listbox id="cashBankListBox" mold="paging"
            emptyMessage="No voucher Found in the list" height="auto"
            width="auto">
            <listhead>
                <listheader>Voucher Number</listheader>
                <listheader>Voucher Date</listheader>
                <listheader>Type</listheader>
                <listheader>Currency</listheader>
                <listheader>Rate</listheader>
                <listheader>Cheque Number</listheader>
                <listheader>Cheque Date</listheader>
                <template name="model">
                    <listitem>
                        <listcell>
                            <label
                                value="${each.cashBankVoucherNumber}" />
                        </listcell>

                        <listcell>
                            <label value="${each.cashBankVoucherDate}" />
                        </listcell>

                        <listcell>
                            <label value="${each.cashBankType}" />
                        </listcell>


                        <listcell>
                            <label value="${each.cashBankCurrency}" />
                        </listcell>


                        <listcell>
                            <label value="${each.cashBankRate}" />
                        </listcell>

                        <listcell>
                            <label value="${each.cashBankChequeNo}" />
                        </listcell>

                        <listcell>
                            <label value="${each.cashBankChequeDate}" />
                        </listcell>
                    </listitem>
                </template>
            </listhead>
        </listbox>
```

And I attached this Controller :

```
public class CashBankController extends SelectorComposer<Component> {
    @Wire
    private Listbox cashBankListBox;
    CashBank cashBankObject = new CashBank(); //model class CashBank

    //there is no problem with service layers..
    private ICashBankService iCashBankService = CashBankServiceImpl.getInstance();

    private ListModelList<CashBank> lst = (ListModelList<CashBank>) iCashBankService.getAllCashBank();

    @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes"})
    @Override
    public void doAfterCompose(Component comp) throws Exception {
        super.doAfterCompose(comp);
        cashBankListBox.setItemRenderer(new ListitemRenderer() {

            @Override
            public void render(Listitem item, Object arg1, int arg2) throws Exception {
                CashBank value = (CashBank) arg1;
                item.appendChild(new Listcell(value.getCashBankVoucherNumber()));
                item.appendChild(new Listcell(value.getCashBankVoucherDate().toString()));
                item.appendChild(new Listcell(value.getCashBankType()));
                item.appendChild(new Listcell(value.getCashBankCurrency()));
                // item.appendChild(new
                // Listcell(value.getCashBankRate().toString()));
                item.appendChild(new Listcell(value.getCashBankChequeDate().toString()));
                item.appendChild(new Listcell(value.getCashBankChequeNo()));
                item.setValue(value);
            }
        });
        cashBankListBox.setModel(new ListModelList<CashBank>(lst));
    }
}
```

The service layers seems to work fine
but I'm getting this error :

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Filtered request failed.
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:384)
    org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125) 
root cause 
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.zkoss.zul.ListModelList
    com.hmt.controller.CashBankController.<init>(CashBankController.java:76)
```

Comment: next time please spend few more minutes to properly write your question. It'll help all of us :-)

Comment: Also see that your order of the code stays correct. the original java code provided was never going to compile.

Answer (score 2):

you cannot cast an `ArrayList` to `ListModelList`

to solve your problem change

```
private ListModelList<CashBank> lst = (ListModelList<CashBank>) iCashBankService.getAllCashBank();
```

with

```
private ListModelList<CashBank> lst = new ListModelList<CashBank>(iCashBankService.getAllCashBank());
```